# How does Jupiter work

Tags: jupiter, power-management

Jupiter is a powersaving applet, which can switch between maximum power, high power and save power. Definitely it does more than just setting the CPU speed, as the recommendations of powertop change at least when in High Power mode or Save Power mode. The main page of Jupiter claims that kernel settings are tweaked for powersaving. Does anybody know which tweaks are applied by Jupiter?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just grokked the code from sourceforge. It boils down to:

- display some tray icons based on live data from `/proc`
- access some `/sys/devices/`
- toggle bluetooth, display, wlan, sound via, you guessed it, `/sys`
- execute some bash scripts that write some hard coded data to `/sys` and `/proc` for battery and power, touching laptop_mode, and some usual suspects that are all either recommendations by powertop or easily found on the net.
- Interestingly assumes all graphics are `radeon` and all sound is `snd_hda_intel`, but does no harm if they aren't.

Not really rocket science but one may derive the one or the other hint for improving any default power manager that only switches the governors.